# How can I install any package in a particular directory with apt-get?

Tags: apt

I would like to know if there is any way that I can make apt-get to install packages in a directory other than /usr/bin. 
Say I want apt-get to install all the packages from now on to /software. Its this possible in anyway ? I want something to work like --prefix option that we use while compiling source.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use *dpkg* instead of apt-get which will give you more options.
One of the option is to specify an installation directory. You can execute `sudo dpkg -i file.deb --instdir=destdir` where *destdir* is your desired installation directory.

Comment: doesn't help :(. dpkg: error processing --instdir=/usr/xx (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
$ ls -l /usr/xx/
total 0

Comment: Does the folder /usr/xx exists?